# concdtional img src inside grdiview image template

Tags: image, templates, gridview

I m using image template inside a gridview like this

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div1<%# Eval("bank_id") %>');">
                            <img alt="" id="imgdiv1<%# Eval("bank_id") %>" width="20px" border="0" src="../Images/Plus.gif" />

                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

here i am using `src="../Images/Plus.gif"` but i want to set to path conditionaly.like if `Eval("bank_id")` is -1 then there should no image displayed or path to b set.is there any one help me to set the conditonal image path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can small trick here. instead of bind your data directly to your image you could call some function that 'll send to it directly the data from DB then in that function you check for that value and based on what you need you return the correct string(correct image src).

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="20px">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="JavaScript:divexpandcollapse('div1<%# Eval("bank_id") %>');">
            <img alt="" id='<%#getImageSRC(int.Parse(Eval("bank_id").ToString())) %>' width="20px" border="0" src="../Images/Plus.gif" />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then in your cs file:

```
public string getImageSRC(int bankId)
{
    if (bankId < 0)
        return "";
    else
        return "/bank-images/" + bankId + ".jpeg";//return here the correct image path
}
```

Comment: i just want to make `src=""` when bank_id is -1

Comment: sorry it's just missing #. it should be '<%# %>

Comment: sir ur idea is goog but i used in another way like used function on src like this `<img alt="" id="imgdiv1<%# Eval("bank_id") %>" width="20px" border="0" src='<%#getImageSRC(int.Parse(Eval("bank_id").ToString())) %>' />`